# Sleep in CMD - Need dirty workaround

Tags: windows, cmd, sleep

If you script something in .cmd and need your program to sleep, you usually have several options.
You can either use

```
ping -n 5 localhost > nul
```

or

```
timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK > nul
```

or call the Start-Sleep Method from powershell.

Here is my problem: All those methods spawn additional Processes. If you use the timeout-method for example, there is the following process created:

[image]

Same for the ping-method. If you use Start-Sleep, a powershell-process is created.
For reasons which are complicated to explain (and not very interesting for others anyway), i canot do this. I somehow have to make sure my .cmd-Script stops for around 5 seconds.
Can anyone think of a dirty trick, what to do, to make the .cmd-Scrpt pause for around 5-7 Seconds? The only requirements are: (1) no sub-processes are spawned and (2) not too ressource intensive (CPU usage shouldnt go too high)

Comment: What you're asking is not possible. Batch or .cmd files are not multithreaded, so if it is paused, it can't do anything to either time anything or to resume without user input. That's why everything you see in previous solutions end up spawning an external process to do the actual timing of the delay.

Comment: Even if we can think of ideas to do this, we need to be able to provide that in context of the rest of your code. In order to do that, you will need to [edit] your code, to submit a real world example. For instance, a delay is often required to allow time for something else to run and complete before continuing, just delaying a script seems illogical. Also it would be helpful if you were to explain why you'd need this. The only reason I can think of would be that you're running something maliciously, and trying to prevent the victim from being able to detect so.

Comment: If `cmd` had a native sleep function there'd be no need for these hacks to begin with. With sufficient ingenuity you can write a busy waiting loop around the output of the built in `%time%` primitive, but as this would involve busy waiting it wouldn't be at all preferable to launching a process.

Comment: You would also need to explain exactly what. "too high" in relation to "CPU usage" means, and how that is relavant. Because you could just use a basic `For` loop with something like `@For /L %%G In (1,1,4200000) Do @Rem`. _I've just actually tested this on an oldish notebook, it took six seconds, (you said 5-7 seconds), and the CPU usage went to around 17%, (IMO not too high)_.

Comment: @Compo: given the very wide variety of processors and their different speeds for single-threaded code, a loop using a constant number of iterations is even worse than spinning over `%time%`. On my (not too new) machine the loop finishes in 4 seconds, newer machines will likely be faster. CPU usage will be more or less inversely proportional to the number of (hardware) threads, since the loop will occupy no more than one of them. Of course the approach is more or less usable if you know exactly what machine it'll be running on, since you can tune the iterations to that.

Comment: I'm aware of the variances @JeroenMostert, but if the OP is not capable of adjusting `4200000` to suit their wanted timings, or their target machine(s) timings are unknown, those are both outside of the scope of the asked question as it currently stands.

Comment: I appears that if your script were written in PowerShell, that `Start-Sleep` does not create a new process. At least, I do not see it in `procexp.exe`. Do you know that it does? Of course, if you invoke powershell.exe or pwsh.exe from the .cmd script it will be required to start a new process.

Comment: If you can't trust your users to not kill arbitrary programs in Taskmanager you might have bigger problems than a sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
    @echo off

    call :wait 5

    goto :eof

    :wait
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set "HOW=%1"
    set "CNT=0"

    call :GetTime NOW

    :again
    call :GetTime NEXT
    if not "!NOW!" == "!NEXT!" (
        set /A "CNT+=1"
        set "NOW=!NEXT!"
    ) else (
        goto :again
    )
    if not "!CNT!" == "%HOW%" (
        goto :again
    )
    endlocal
    goto :eof
    
    :GetTime
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,* delims=,: " %%a in ('%time%') do (
        set "%1=%%c"
    )
    goto :eof
```